# AI for image validity prediction

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I have an application deployed and running fullscreen on hundreds computers. Sometimes the application crashes and screen displays Windows desktop or external windows pop up (system, external programms...). I have several thousands of screenshots of ok cases and hundreds of ko cases and want to automatise the ko detection in the future.
Is an ai algorithm/api exist which can be feed with ok and ko screenshots in inputs and to compute a model for future prediction ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a standard job for a convolutional neural network. There are plenty of tutorials that will walk you through setting one up, and there are many good networks that are pre-created for you.

I like this site for good introductory tutorials:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples

VGG, Inception, Mobilenet are all common convolutional network architectures that perform quite well in a wide variety of cases.

The most important thing for you to know when you train up a model like this is to balance the KO and OK classes. If you have fewer KO examples than OK examples you will bias your algorithm towards predicting OK. You can solve this problem simply by oversampling the KO examples, just re-use them as needed so that you have a roughly 50/50 split between the two classes.

Everything else should be pretty easy. Grab a CNN tutorial like MNIST or CIFAR-10 and set it up. Once you've followed a tutorial you should be ready to try it out on your dataset.

Also you'll probably do well to reduce the size of your images, I think somewhere in the range of 224x224 is generally a good balance between detail and computation time.